# Variaveis $_SESSION reseta após recarregar página em PHP

Tags: php, session

Olá. Estou tentando realizar um sistema de login bem simples com session e não estou conseguindo manter as variáveis $_SESSION salvas, pois elas se perdem toda vez que tem reload na página.

Meu index.php

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST["login"])){
        $_SESSION["autenticado"] = true;
    }
?>  
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include("header.php"); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
        include("cabecalho.php");
        include("corpo.php");
        include("rodape.php");
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Dentro do cabecalho.php existe a função que verifica login e etc. Quando eu utilizo a função de login, o session funciona normalmente, porém quando eu recarrego a página, ou utilizo alguma função que me manda de volta pro index.php (que dá include tudo de novo) as variaveis $_SESSION["autenticado"] fica nula.

Por que isso está acontecendo? O que devo fazer para as variáveis continuarem com seus valores guarados mesmo recarregando a página?

PS: só tem session_start() no index.php porque ela que dá include em todas outras páginas e sempre que carrega-se uma nova página, ela passa pelo index.php, então sempre haverá session_start antes de mais nada.

Comment: Qual é o restante do código? Tem como postá-lo? Talvez tenha algo na função de login que esteja afetando o funcionamento.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisará dar o session_start() em todas as páginas protegidas, com um fragmento do tipo:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["autenticado"]))
    {
         header("Location: login.html")
    }
?>
```

Se não existir a variável `$_SESSION["autenticado"]` na sessão, redireciona para a página de login que possui um form de login. O action desse form verifica a validade dos dados de login e se o login for efetuado com sucesso,
você deverá criar essa variável `$_SESSION["autenticado"]` e redirecionar para a página protegida.

## Exemplo de login com PHP utilizando session

**index.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["autenticado"]))
{
    header("Location: login.html");
}
else
{
    header("Location: protegida1.php");        
}
```

Essa é a página de entrada. Ela verifica se o usuário já está logado. Caso esteja manda pra página interna do sistema, caso não, manda o usuário para o form de login.

**login.html**

```
<h2>Por favor, efetue o login para acessar o sistema</h2>

<form action="processa_login.php" method="post">

    Login: <input type="text" name="login"><br>
    Senha: <input type="password" name="senha">

    <input type="submit" value="Logar">

</form>
```

login.html é um form que envia os dados de login para serem verificados pelo script processa_login.php. Perceba que o formulário possui o method post e o script a seguir utilizará $_POST para verificar os dados enviados. Utilize login igual a **teste** e senha **12345** para testar.

**processa_login.php**

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST["login"]) || !isset($_POST["senha"]))
{
    header("Location: login.html");
}

if($_POST["login"]=="teste" && $_POST["senha"]=="12345")
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["autenticado"] = true;
    
    header("Location: protegida1.php");
}
else
{
    header("Location: login.html");    
}
```

São verificadas antes de tudo se as variáveis de login foram enviadas. Em seguida é verificado se o par login e senha indicam um login válido. Caso seja um login válido, inicia a sessão, cria a variável $_SESSION["autenticado"] e envia para a página protegida1.php, caso contrário volta para o form de login.

**protegida1.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["autenticado"]))
    {
        header("Location: login.html");
    }
?>  
<h2> Página protegida 1</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

<a href="protegida2.php">Ir para a página protegida 2</a>
<br><br>
<a href="deslogar.php">Sair do sistema(logoff)</a>
```

Esta é a primeira página no sistema após o login. Se um usuário tentar acessar essa página diretamente sem antes ter efetuado o login corretamente, será redirecionado pro form de login.

**protegida2.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["autenticado"]))
    {
        header("Location: login.html");
    }
?>  
<h2> Página protegida 2</h2>

<p>Lalala lerolero lolololol.</p>

<a href="protegida1.php">Voltar para a página protegida 1</a>
<br><br>
<a href="deslogar.php">Sair do sistema(logoff)</a>
```

protegida2.php é outra página protegida apenas para mostrar que o login se mantém.

**deslogar.php**

```
<?php

// Limpa a sessão 
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
session_regenerate_id(true);    

header("Location: login.html");
```

Esse código de limpar a sessão é realmente uma receita de bolo par matar a sessão do usuário.

Se essa resposta tiver lhe ajudado, marque-a como aceita e dê +1 para me dar pontos de reputação.

Qualquer dúvida vamos nos falando aqui em baixo nos comentários.

Um grande abraço.